# Are there tools to allow export of Console.app output with same format?

Tags: macos, terminal, software-recommendation, logs, console

So for years I have not found a way to export a clean output of results collected in the macOS Console app

I primarily want to save my results in the same format as the data is organized in the console app I would be so grateful. Saving them as plain text is unorganized and messy.

- There was one app years ago that I forgot the name of that was an alternative to console and let you export neat organize files, but I can't find it anymore.

Are there apps or tricks to help with this - especially on macOS Ventura?

Answer (score 3):

Check out Howard Oakley's Consolation3 and Ulbow 1.8 apps (one may even be the one you've forgotten). He has a whole range of very useful utilities, and very comprehensive notes on their uses. https://eclecticlight.co/consolation-t2m2-and-log-utilities/

Allows comprehensive log searching and exporting.

Ulbow just fixed an issue exporting to CSV - https://eclecticlight.co/2022/12/26/ulbow-1-8-a-present-for-boxing-day/

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. There is a boat load of cool stuff in here. While thisisnt not the app I was referring to in the past I forgot the name of this is great stuff. Sadly the app I used to used look almost the same as console but also add a lot more option and even an export button that create a file that opening in console and kept the same format. thanks again!!!